# Регулярное выражение для ФИО на кириллице

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть форма с отдельными полями для фамилии, имени и отчества, хотелось бы прикрутить к ней умную валидацию отсекающую большую часть некорректно введенных данных, но при этом чтобы регулярное выражение было наиболее емким (не отсекло лишнего). Например чтобы в качестве работника предприятия нельзя было зарегистрировать абстрактного C-3PO!

На данный момент остановился на `^[А-ЯЁа-яё '-]+$`

Дефис для двойных имён/фамилий + в некоторых культурах могут использоваться дополнительные имена, для этого добавил пробел. Ну и апостроф для всяких там О'Рейли. Вроде бы регулярка теперь не отсекает ничего лишнего, но при этом даёт спокойно писать нелепые вещи вида `АбЫрВ--Алг'' Пур`, недостаточно строгая. Доступность смены регистра однако считаю допустимой из-за фамилий вида МакКонахи.

Резюме: кто-то еще сталкивался с подобными дилеммами? Каким образом решали? Наиболее строгую регулярку (отсекающую максимум бредовых комбинаций символов) сделаю принятым ответом. Вопрос кажется достаточно актуальным и наиболее полного ответа на него не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Kkt4IB/1)

`$pattern = '/^(?=.{1,40}$)[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+(?:[-' ][а-яёА-ЯЁ]+)*$/';`

**Разбор** регулярного выражения:

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?=.{1,40}$)` - длина от 1 до 40, кроме символов разрыва строки в строке
- `[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+` - 1 и более русских символов
- `(?:` - начало повторной группы, не выполняющей захват, 0 или более раз, соответствующие последовательностям

  - `[-' ]` - символ `'`, `-`, или пробел
  - `[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+` -  1 и более русских символов
- `)*` - конец группировки
- `$` - конец строки

Хотелось бы сказать большое спасибо @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0):

как-то так:

```
([А-Яа-яёЁ]+['\s-]{0,1})+
```

Answer (score 0):

может так

```
^[А-Я][А-Яа-я']+\s?
```

если был бы некий список, было бы проще с регуляркой. а то наугад приходится )

Comment: `ёЁ` тоже нужно добавлять, т.к. оно не входит в `а-яА-Я`